# Oracle: calculate day fraction of DATE type column

Tags: database, oracle, date-formatting

I have a DATE type column in Oracle table. 
As I understand it holds information about hours, minutes and seconds. I need to get a day Fraction of this column. Currently I am using this construction:

```
TO_CHAR(p.snaptime, 'HH24')/24 + TO_CHAR(p.snaptime, 'MI')/1440 + TO_CHAR(p.snaptime, 'SS')/86400
```

Is there more elegant (=shorter) way to get the same? Preferably even more time/CPU efficient for calculating it by Oracle. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hmmm.  How about this?

```
select (p.snaptime - trunc(p.snaptime))
```

The difference of two dates is a number.  In this case, the number will represent the time of the day.  If you wanted this in some other unit, then you can convert by multiplication (`* 24` for hours, `* 24 * 60` for minutes, `* 24 * 60 * 60` for seconds).